# How can i update an item in a string array and update the ListView accordingly?

Tags: android, arrays, listview, android-listview

I have a code where i am initially populating a listview with a string array by using a custom adapter. I want to update the fields in string array accordingly, and hence update the listview, is there a way to edit a string array? The problem is that my string array doesnt just consist of a string, it consists of an int field which i update acc to the user.

```
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.NumberPicker;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.Toolbar;


public class CashRegisterActivity extends Activity {

    NumberPicker numberPicker;
    EditText magnitude;
    ListView cashRegisterListview;
    int a0=0,a1=0,a2=0,a3=0,a4=0,a5=0,a6=0,a7=0,a8=0,a9=0;
    String[] list= {"1000 x " + a0, "500 x " + a1, "100 x " + a2, "50 x " + a3, "20 x " + a4,
            "10 x " + a5, "5 x " + a6, "2 x " + a7, "1 x " + a8, "0.5 x " + a9};
    CustomCashlistAdapter customCashlistAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_cash_register);
        Toolbar tb = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
        setActionBar(tb);
        cashRegisterListview = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.cashRegisterListview);
        magnitude=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.magnitude);
        numberPicker = (NumberPicker)findViewById(R.id.numberPicker);
        numberPicker.setDisplayedValues(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.inr_picker_display));
        numberPicker.setEnabled(true);
        numberPicker.setMaxValue(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.inr_picker_display).length - 1);
        numberPicker.setMinValue(0);
        customCashlistAdapter = new CustomCashlistAdapter(this,list);
        cashRegisterListview.setAdapter(customCashlistAdapter);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setTitle("Cash Register");
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        else if (id == android.R.id.home){
            finish();
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    //Add Selection
    public void addSelection(View view){
        double currentSelection = 0;
        int currentMagnitude = Integer.parseInt(magnitude.getText().toString());
        switch (numberPicker.getValue()){
            case 0:
                currentSelection=1000;a0=currentMagnitude;Toast.makeText(this,""+a0,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case 1:
                currentSelection=500;a1=currentMagnitude;
                break;
            case 2:
                currentSelection=100;a2=currentMagnitude;
                break;
            case 3:
                currentSelection=50;a3=currentMagnitude;
                break;
            case 4:
                currentSelection=20;a4=currentMagnitude;
                break;
            case 5:
                currentSelection=10;a5=currentMagnitude;
                break;
            case 6:
                currentSelection=5;a6=currentMagnitude;
                break;
            case 7:
                currentSelection=2;a7=currentMagnitude;
                break;
            case 8:
                currentSelection=1;a8=currentMagnitude;
                break;
            case 9:
                currentSelection=0.5;a9=currentMagnitude;
                break;
        }
        customCashlistAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

PS: I don't get why people downvote if they can't help. It's not like everyone is Dennis Ritchie here.

Comment: Down vote may be because, you didn't mention the error you are getting and also the logcat is missing.

Comment: @PrerakSola Maybe because i am not getting any errors? I have specifically asked for a method to update the listview, nowhere have i mentioned that i have any errors. A downvote seems acceptable if you give an answer and the answer seems to easy. Its silly if people downvote and the question remains unanswered. I think there is something inherently wrong with the stack community if people can't get help here.

Comment: Well, to make you aware, things work a bit differently over here. Here we help the people who are unable to **resolve** something. This is neither a coding service nor a search/research engine. You need to do those things on your own.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with the help of a 2nd list:

```
String[] helperlist = {"1000 x ", "500 x ", "100 x ", "50 x ", "20 x ", "10 x ", "5 x ", "2 x ", "1 x ", "0.5 x "};
list[x] = helperlist[x] + ax;
```

where "ax" is the value you changed and "x" is the position of that value in your list.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using more complex collection class like `ArrayList` you can add, remove, trim and many other things by single invoke.